# Constants/properties of a very small-scale and compact universe that is still recognisably like our own (and is it possible)

Tags: internal-consistency, physics, worldbuilding-process, universe

Is it possible to tweak the gravitational constant and the "starting amount" of matter so that:

- My universe has 1-5 galaxies
- There are a few thousand stars per galaxy (a solution with an order
  of magnitude more or less stars is fine)
- The orbit sizes relative to the sizes of the bodies of mass involved
  are at least 5 times smaller
- A planet like our own (preferably with tectonics aka. crust, mantle
  and core) that orbits a star and has 0.8 to 1.3G is 500-2000km
  (range is for a bit of flexibility although I don't mind going under
  500km that much) in diameter and is able to be created by natural
  processes in the first place

I would prefer to keep the universe as tight, compact and generally small-scale as possible and any insights would be great to creating a more realistic vision of my universe before starting to actually design layout/properties of planets, stars, solar-systems, etc.

Comment: I seem to recall that our universe wouldn't exist as we know it if the value of G were anything other than it is now (e.g., planets don't form, the Big Bang never happens, etc.).

Comment: @Frostfyre, it's not just G but a multitude of fundamental parameters, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-tuned_Universe (But then again who knows if those parameters and the physics behind it were to be different what kind of an universe would be the result.)

Comment: The transformation you describe is not well-defined.  For example, the fine-structure constant $\alpha$ is equal to $k_\text{e}e^2/\hbar c$: so it should increase by 20... but $\alpha=c\mu_0/2R_\text{K}$, so it should decrease by 1/20?  The answer is that the other constants need to change as well.  You need to tell us the new values of [exactly five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Systems_of_natural_units) constants to specify the new values of all the other physical constants.

Comment: Now that this question is closed, I would ask the physics.se for help on choosing the new values of constants so that such a universe is possible.

Comment: The strong force that makes up nuclei can be thought of as exchanging virtual pion particles that it doesn't have energy to make.  This works as long as the range of the exchange is so short that the uncertainty principle allows it - making the value of c 1/20th of the current value means that large nuclei just can't form at all.

Comment: Nice to see that you've added some desired numbers, but you might want to consider that units are also tied to the fundamental constants.  For example, the meter is defined in terms of the speed of light, so "500 kilometers" will get 20 times smaller, times whatever the change in the frequency of the cesium ground-state hyperfine transition is (which defines the second).

Comment: @2012rcampion Good point which brought an important aspect of changing the speed of light; it might change the way atoms interact. I basically want to try to create a small-scale and compact universe that has the same chemistry and types of planets (although smaller in scale and maybe without tectonics) because that way I can base my universe's biology on real biology rather than having to make something up which would be almost definitely wrong/unrealistic due to the overwhelming amount of unknown factors meaning we might not even be able to change the speed of light while preserving realism.

Comment: @godofllamas - Is there a particular outcome you are looking for here?  If you simply want a couple small and very isolated galaxies, then there is no reason these galaxies couldn't have been ejected by gravity from the mainstay of the universe and after enough years are floating so far away from anything else that they may as well be their own 4 star universe?  Then you would simply need a reason for some very tight orbits (densities might work here?)

Comment: @Twelfth I've decided that changing the speed of light is too risky for trying to create a realistic semi-predictable universe because the energy produced from nuclear fusion would change which would in turn change how the stars in that universe would work (and if they're even possible with a stronger/weaker speed of light) so it's probably best to leave light alone so I've removed it from the original question. Also, I would think that raising the gravitational constant would solve both the 3rd and 4th requirement but I don't know what other side effects it has.

Comment: You could up-vote both.... That is why we are allotted a certain number of votes.

Comment: @godofllamas - Not sure when the last edit to your question was, but the questions changed a lot.   I think the simplest thing here is the star wars style 'a galaxy far far away'.   Early in our universes history, this galaxy (or 5 galaxies) got flung out at a pretty incredible speed and never stopped...now it's so far away that it may as well be it's own universe.  And there is no reason this galaxy couldn't contain a few massive stars that generated the elements you require for an earth like world before going supernova and spreading these elements out for them to later form into an Earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you can get away with weakening gravity but leaving the other 3 forces the same...gravity at 95% weaker and magnetic attraction/repulsion at 100% may see your atoms fly apart at a molecular level.

Your universe is going to contain far less energy.  Mass to energy conversion is based on the speed of light, so your stars that depend on these fusions as their heat source will have less energy to work with which may start to inhibit their ability to even become stars.  Limiting gravity will also affect the pressure these stars are put under...you'll likely need far larger stars to support life on the planets surrounding it.

Also note that the generation of heavier elements is based on fusion occurring in extremely large stars.  These extremely large stars will have to be much larger to get the pressures they require for large element fusion (a bit counter-intuitive to your idea).  It's possible that the universe you describe here outright fails to generate oxygen and heavier elements out to iron.

Remember that a galaxy doesn't 'just form'...a single star creates heavier elements, goes supernova ejecting the newly formed elements, and then the resulting mass is there for the next systems to form from (repeat).  A few thousand star systems is exceedingly tiny and I'm not sure if you are giving the room for large stars to create the elements we have in today's earth.

I think your biggest issue here is your stars need to be much larger to make up for the lower gravity, they emit far less energy, and it's doubtful heavy elements will form.

Comment: Gravity isn't a meaningful force at the atomic level, weakening it has no effect on anything to do with chemistry.  I do agree with the rest of your gripes--this micro-universe isn't going to have planets.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Twelfth's objections I think you have an end-of-life problem with stars.

First, consider $E=mc^2$.

Assuming the periodic table is unchanged this means the energy output of fusion is only $1\%$ of what we see.  You'll need a lot more mass to get the same energy output from a star--which is a good thing as you'll also need much of this extra mass just to hold the star together.  (It would be $10\times$ if the star were the same size but the extra mass means the star will also be bigger.  I'm not confident of my ability to figure out how much bigger.)

Second, consider the equation of the event horizon of a black hole: $$r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$$

Both $G$ and $c$ have been cut to $1/10^\text{th}$ of our values, but note the $c$ term is squared.  Thus $r_s$ is $10\times$ what it would be in our universe.

In our universe the smallest black hole that can form by simple compression is about 3 solar masses.  Wikipedia says 2.95km per solar mass for the radius of a simple black hole, thus we are looking at 8.85km radius in our universe.  In this universe that's 88.5km.

Now, lets look at neutron stars.  Take, for example, one with mass $1.4~M_\text{Sun}$ and diameter $20~
\text{km}$.  This is set by the degeneracy pressure and I don't think this will change in your universe.  Note that the neutron star is considerably smaller than a black hole of the same mass--in other words, a neutron star can't exist because it's going to be crushed into a black hole.

Edit:  I focused on the math too much and forgot to tie these two bits together:

The smallest stars are about .1 solar mass.  However, in this universe they must be at least 10x this, 1 solar mass.  At best we have a narrow band in which stars can become a white dwarf but that's a low bound, I don't think this band actually exists.  Thus all dead stars become black holes.